# Edit post & page option does not display on latest wordpress

Tags: posts, themes, pages, wp-admin, links

I am not able to edit the WordPress default posts/pages from front-end. I have tried to deactivate all plugins, check/uncheck toolbar option(from profile) and also wp_footer() function in the file.

But no luck any suggestion?

Comment: Where are you expecting to see an edit link?

Comment: Have you tried switching back to the default theme? Some theme developers tend to disable it, because it's "pushing" their design - instead of working around it.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, Thanks for your response. I expect to see in header area admin bar. Check this: https://prnt.sc/25ynjpw

Comment: @WPTricksDK, Thanks for your response. I have tried with another theme and it's working. BUT it was working with my current theme before WordPress update

Comment: @MaharshiGadhavi - Okay, that's weird then. Are you using any caching plugins?

Comment: Is just the edit link missing, or the entire toolbar?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, thanks for your response. Whole toolbar is displaying but only Edit Page/post option does not display.

Comment: @WPTricksDK, No, I am not using any caching plugin and i have also deactivated all the plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and resolved with below code.

```
function menu_shapespace_node_landearth($wp_admin_bar) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('edit');
}
//add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'menu_shapespace_node_landearth', 999);
```